# Which spaces are homotopy equivalent in an h-cobordism?

Tags: manifolds, homotopy-theory, cobordism

All the definitions I've found for h-cobordisms define it as a cobordism $(W,M,N)$ such that the inclusions $i_M:M\rightarrow W$ and $i_N:N\rightarrow W$ are homotopy equivalences. But this doesn't make sense to me since we can't compose these maps with each other.

So maybe the definition means that $i_M$ is a homotopy equivalence with respect to some implied function $i'_M:W\rightarrow M$ (and $i_N$ is, separately, its own homotopy equivalence). My guess is that we would use some retract from $W$ to the image of $M$ and compose that with the inverse of $i_M$; this would mean (identifying $M$ with its image in $W$) that there is a deformation retract from $W$ to $M$ (and another one from $W$ to $N$).

This seems perfectly reasonable, but that doesn't seem to match [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688864/cobordism-and-h-cobordism), which describes an h-cobordism as a cobordism where $M$ and $N$ are homotopy equivalent as subsets of $W$. I think that's implied by the definition I described above (reverse the retraction from $W$ to $M$, then retract $W$ to $N$, and the composition gives a homotopy from $M$ to $N$), but it seems like a homotopy from $M$ to $N$ is a weaker condition.

Are they equivalent? If there is a homotopy from $M$ to $N$ within $W$, then one could take the subset of $W$ of points in the image of the homotopy. This should be its own manifold, which would satisfy the first definition.

Am I on the right track with any of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confused about what a "homotopy equivalence" is.  A homotopy equivalence is a map $f:X\to Y$ such that *there exists* a map $g:Y\to X$ such that $fg$ and $gf$ are homotopic to the identity maps.  So a homotopy equivalence is just a single map $f$; you don't have to specify a homotopy inverse map $g$ to call $f$ a homotopy equivalence.

So when someone says $i_M:M\to W$ and $i_N:N\to W$ are homotopy equivalences, it means just that: $i_M:M\to W$ is a homotopy equivalence, and also $i_N:N\to W$ is a homotopy equivalence.  It doesn't mean they are homotopy inverses of each other.

I would not worry about the question you linked, which asked (rather bizarrely) for an explanation of $h$-cobordism that is not "math based".  The description of $h$-cobordism given in the answer was not intended as a precise definition but was just an attempt to convey some intuition.  (Indeed, it is not clear to me what it even means for $M$ and $N$ to be "homotopic in $W$".  I guess maybe it means there is a homotopy equivalence $f:M\to N$ such that $i_Nf$ is homotopic to $i_M$.  To get such an $f$, you can just take $f=gi_M$ where $g$ is a homotopic inverse of $i_N$.  This is definitely a weaker condition than $i_M$ and $i_N$ both being homotopy equivalences, since for instance $W$ could be disconnected with $M$ and $N$ in just one of the components.)

Comment: Okay, that's very helpful. I meant roughly what you said about "homotopic in $W$"; I was thinking of something like a homotopy $F:[0,1]\times X\rightarrow W$ such that $F(0,X)$ is homeomorphic to the embedding of $M$ in $W$, and $F(1,X)$ is homemorphic to $N$ in $W$ (so, $X=M$ I guess?). 

As a follow-up: Even if the homotopy inverse $g$ is not specified, can we say that for an h-cobordism, it would be a deformation retract from $W$ to the embedding of $M$ into $W$?

Comment: Yes, $i_M$ being a homotopy equivalence implies that $M$ is a deformation retract of $W$.  (This is not obvious, and is a consequence of the fact that $i_M$ is a cofibration.)

Comment: If I take any two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ and there is an embedding $g$ from $X$ into $Y$, and I know that embedding is a homotopy equivalence, does that imply that the image of $X$ Is a deformation retract? I would expect (and maybe this is my issue) that I could form the required homotopy inverse $g$ by gluing the inverse of the embedding to some other function on the rest of $Y$. Composing $f\circ g$ gives a retraction(?) that we know is homotopic to the identity on $Y$.

Comment: No.  For a really simple counterexample, let $Y=[0,1]$ and $X=(0,1)$; then $X$ cannot be a retract of $Y$ since $X$ is not compact.